# How to print elements of a list two by two in separate lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Assuming I have the following list:

```
input_list = [1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 2]
```

How can I print its elements two by two like so:

```
1 4
6 7
9 2
```

**Note:** The length of the list is always even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `zip()` for this -

```
for i, j in zip(input_list[0::2], input_list[1::2]):
     print (i , j)
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively without `zip`ing:

```
for i in range(0, len(input_list), 2):
    print(input_list[i], input_list[i+1])
```